# Check if columns in a row is occupied with value, with maximum occupied columns is limited to 3

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to copy diagonal data and paste it in a row.
With criteria:

1. Limit the columns in Paste Range so it can only uses 3 columns in a row.
2. Depending on how much rows in Copy Range, the rows in Paste Range is divided by 3 from Copy Range.
   If Copy Range have 3 rows, it will be paste on 1 row in Paste Range.
   If Copy Range have 6 rows, it will be paste on 2 row in Paste Range, etc.
3. The SUM/total of the value in every rows in Paste Range, cannot exceeded 30.

Here's my current code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeDiagonalData()
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim pasteRange As Range
    ' Set copyRange to the range of diagonal data
    Set copyRange = Range("A1:I9")
    ' Determine the number of columns in the copyRange
    Dim numCols As Integer
    numCols = copyRange.Columns.Count
    ' Determine the number of rows needed in the pasteRange
    Dim numRows As Integer
    numRows = numCols / 3
    ' Set pasteRange to start at A10 and have a maximum of 3 columns
    Set pasteRange = Range("A10").Resize(numRows, 3)
    ' Loop through each column of the copyRange
    Dim copyCol As Range
    For Each copyCol In copyRange.Columns
        ' Loop through each cell in the current column of the copyRange
        Dim copyCell As Range
        For Each copyCell In copyCol.Cells
            ' Check if the current cell in the copyRange has data
            If Not IsEmpty(copyCell.Value) Then
                ' Determine the next available row in the current column of the pasteRange
                Dim nextRow As Integer
                nextRow = GetNextAvailableRow(copyCol.Column, pasteRange)
                ' Check if the first row in the pasteRange has fewer than 3 occupied cells
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(pasteRange.Rows(1)) < 3 Then
                    ' Copy the data from the current cell in the copyRange and paste it into the first available row of the pasteRange
                    pasteRange.Cells(nextRow, WorksheetFunction.CountA(pasteRange.Rows(nextRow)) + 1).Value = copyCell.Value
                    ' Check if the second row in the pasteRange has fewer than 3 occupied cells
                ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(pasteRange.Rows(2)) < 3 Then
                    'Copy the data from the current cell in the copyRange and paste it into the second available row of the pasteRange
                    'pasteRange.Cells(nextRow + 1, WorksheetFunction.CountA(pasteRange.Rows(nextRow + 2)) + 1).Value = copyCell.Value
                    pasteRange.Cells(nextRow + 1, copyCol.Column - copyRange.Column + 1).Value = copyCell.Value
                ' Check if the third row in the pasteRange has fewer than 3 occupied cells
                Else
                    'WorksheetFunction.CountA(pasteRange.Rows(3)) < 3 Then
                    ' Copy the data from the current cell in the copyRange and paste it into the third available row of the pasteRange
                    'pasteRange.Cells(nextRow + 2, WorksheetFunction.CountA(pasteRange.Rows(nextRow + 2)) + 1).Value = copyCell.Value
                    pasteRange.Cells(nextRow + 2, copyCol.Column - copyRange.Column + 2).Value = copyCell.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next copyCell
    Next copyCol
End Sub

Function GetNextAvailableRow(colNum As Integer, pasteRange As Range) As Integer
    'Determine the last occupied row in the current column of the pasteRange
    Dim lastRow As Range
    Set lastRow = pasteRange.Columns(colNum - pasteRange.Column + 1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    'Check if any data was found in the column
    If lastRow Is Nothing Then
        'If no data was found, return the first row of the column in the pasteRange
        GetNextAvailableRow = 1
    Else
        'If data was found, return the next available row in the column of the pasteRange
        GetNextAvailableRow = lastRow.Row + 1
    End If
End Function
```

And here's the code results:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZDWC.png]

But, unfortunately this is not what I want.
The first row and the second row in Paste Range works perfectly. But somehow, when it loops on third rows, it messed up.
What I want is something like this.

[image]

Comment: Will there always be only a single row filled in each column?

Comment: If you ask about the source data, Yes. The source data will always be only a single row filled in each column. But in the column, there's a possibility another data filled in those column. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may benefit from arrays to loop faster and also from method OFFSET.

> [Range.Offset property
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)

Here's the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim MyData As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim vColumn As Long, vrow As Long


Set pasteRange = Range("A10")
Set copyRange = Range("A1:I9")
MyData = copyRange.Value 'take data into array to loop faster

For i = 1 To copyRange.Columns.Count Step 1 'loop trough each column
    For j = 1 To UBound(MyData) Step 1 'loop trough each row
        If MyData(j, i) <> "" Then
            vrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(vColumn / 3, 0)
            pasteRange.Offset(vrow, vColumn).Value = MyData(j, i)
            vColumn = vColumn + 1
            Exit For 'break loop trough rows and go to next column
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'clean variables
Erase MyData
Set copyRange = Nothing
Set pasteRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. 
But it has some problems where the total amount of each row in Paste Range exceeded 30. I want to make it go to the next row if the total of value in a row in Paste Range exceeded 30 (even it only has 2 occupied columns.)

Comment: And, somehow I have source data where there's 1 column that doesn't have any value. I want to copy those value in Copy Range to Paste Range within the same column. This is what I get with your code:

[results](https://i.imgur.com/igVVYSD.png)

But, this is what I expected to get the results:

[expected results](https://i.imgur.com/ps5Q9kj.png)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is just an starting point. You can use the code to modify it properly according to your needs.

Comment: I figure it out using your code after made some adjustments. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because the data is diagonal, we need a unique loop

```
Sub example23(from As Range, toCell As Range)
   Dim fclmns As Long, torow As Long
   Dim v As Variant, cc As Long, trr As Long, tcc As Long, tmp As Variant
   
   fclmns = from.Columns.CountLarge - 1
   Set from = from.Cells(1)
   trr = 0
   tmp = 0
   tcc = 0
   For cc = 0 To fclmns
      v = from.Offset(cc, cc).Value
      If v <> "" Then
         If tmp + v > 30 Or tcc = 3 Then
            trr = trr + 1
            tcc = 0
            tmp = 0
         End If
         tmp = tmp + v
         tcc = tcc + 1
      End If
      toCell.Offset(trr, cc).Value = v
   Next
End Sub

Sub executor()
   Call example23(Me.Range("A1:I9"), Me.Range("A11"))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have source data where there's 1 column that doesn't have any value. I want to copy those value in Copy Range to Paste Range within the same column. This is what I get with your code: [code results](https://i.imgur.com/ifR0QNT.png)

But, this is what I expected to get the results:
[expected results](https://i.imgur.com/ps5Q9kj.png)

Comment: I didn't realize anything about the gaps, your example didn't help either - it didn't have any gaps. Nevertheless, with a small correction it will produce a correct result.

Comment: I get it now. Confuse where I should add if value "".
Thank you. I'll modify the code by myself now.